# How can I pass a reference type between Assemblies referencing a common DLL?

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies

High level: I am trying to build a console app (e.g. ConsoleApp.exe) which can perform some processing on any given DLL which references a certain type defined in ConsoleApp.exe.

I decided, maybe mistakenly, that I would need a companion DLL for ConsoleApp which contained the type or types (e.g. ConsoleClass) which were intended to be referenced by arbirary DLLs. To pull this off, as I don't know of a better way, I have two projects in the ConsoleApp solution, one is a class library (Proving ConsoleApp.dll) and the other is a console application which references the class library project.

At this point, I now am able to copy my ConsoleApp.dll to another relatively unrelated project in a separate solution (e.g. OtherApp.dll), reference it, and write a method which consumes a ConsoleClass instance as a parameter.

Now, in order to arbitrarily process this OtherApp.dll, the ConsoleApp.exe loads that Assembly, instantiates the proper class in that Assembly, and then calls the proper method on that instance. Pertinent lines below hopefully provide context to how I am doing this:

```
Assembly.LoadFrom(path_to_OtherApp_dll);
...
var x = (dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(type_inside_OtherApp_dll);
...
var instance = new ConsoleClass();
x.some_method_call(instance);
```

Ultimately this fails. It seems to be because even though the two projects (ConsoleApp.exe and OtherApp.dll) are referencing the same DLL to define ConsoleClass, the runtime still considers them to be different types.

Any thoughts?

Comment: `(dynamic)Activator.CreateInstance(T)` doesn't make sense. Since you know what type you're instantiating, why not cast to that type directly: `(T)Activator.CreateInstance(T)` (`T := type_inside_OtherApp_dll`)

Comment: In fact, I even suggest you remove the `dynamic`. If you then get a compile-time error at `x.some_method_call(INSTANCE)`, you know that you're indeed passing the wrong type of object, and that you somehow got your assembly references in these two DLL projects wrong.

Comment: well, I cast as dynamic since I personally don't know how to cast to a type that I don't know the literal class name of. I have the type (type_inside_OtherApp_dll) but that was gathered through reflection (something I didn't mention earlier). Since ConsoleApp cannot possibly reference OtherApp.dll at compile time, I cannot literally cast as type_inside_OtherApp_dll in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this will happen when ConsoleApp.dll gets loaded twice.  Once by the main app, again by a plugin, using its local copy.  A type's identity is determined by the assembly it was loaded from.

It isn't that clear to me how that happened.  Your first weapon of choice is Fuslogvw.exe, set it up to log all the binds.  First thing to do is to doctor the plugin project and set the Copy Local property of the ConsoleApp.dll reference to False so that extra copy isn't there to get accidentally used.

Copying the plugin DLLs to the main app build folder is the never-have-trouble solution, you can load them with Assembly.Load().  Or a subdirectory with a .config file that uses the `<probing>` element to allow the CLR to find them.

Comment: That is exactly what was happening. In trying to not make a 5 page long question, I did leave out the fact that I was blindly loading all dlls found as siblings to the targeted one - which allows my app to meet any dependencies it has. Though I'm sure there is a better way. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

1. Define the public interface. Put it to its own interface.dll.
2. Reference interface.dll in your plugin. Let the main class in your plugin.dll implements your interface.
3. Reference interface.dll in your exe.
4. Use Assembly.Load() or Assembly.LoadFrom() to load plugin into your exe.
5. Use CreateInstance() to create instance of your plugin class.
6. Simply cast created plugin to your interface type.

So you don't need "dynamic" or other complicated things. Just easy, go step by step as I wrote and it will work. Good luck.

Comment: Passant's answer got me over this hump, but I will now take a look at structuring my implementation as you have laid out here. Thank you very much for the overview. Very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

What do you by "runtime is considering them to be of differnt type"? does setup ends with some exception of error? does method in x variable receives something it does not recognize or what?